# Get matches from a preg_replace and use them as an array key

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-replace

I want to get matches from a String and use them in a array as key to change the value in the string to the value of the array.

If it would be easier to realize, i can change the fantasy tags from %! also to whatever don't have problems in JS/jQuery. This script is for external JS Files and change some variables, which I can't Access from JS/jQuery. So I want to insert them with PHP and send them minified and compressed to the Browser.

```
$array = array ( 'abc' => 'Test', 'def' => 'Variable', 'ghi' => 'Change' );
$string ='This is just a %!abc!% String and i wanna %!ghi!% the %!def!%';

$string = preg_replace('%!(.*?)!%',$array[$1],$string);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` instead?

Comment: sorry :D Yeah of course. but my main question is, how to get out the string between the tags AND use it as a key in a existing array to put the array value in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [`preg_quote`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to turn the keys of your array into regexes, and then use the values of the array as replacement strings in the array form of [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$array = array ( 'abc' => 'Test', 'def' => 'Variable', 'ghi' => 'Change' );
$string ='This is just a %!abc!% String and i wanna %!ghi!% the %!def!%';
$regexes = array_map(function ($k) { return "/" . preg_quote("%!$k!%") . "/"; }, array_keys($array));
$string = preg_replace($regexes, $array, $string);
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
This is just a Test String and i wanna Change the Variable
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mAh7o)

Comment: Great! Thank you so much :)